# Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. exeption

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my c# app I have a function that restores database from a `.bak` file, I works fine for some `.bak` files. but for some not. here is my code and the exeption:

**C# code:**

```
void RestoreDatabase(String databaseName , String backUpFile , String serverName , String userName , String password)
{
 ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName , userName , password);
 Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
 Restore rstDatabase = new Restore();
 rstDatabase.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
 rstDatabase.Database = databaseName;
 BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile , DeviceType.File);
 rstDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
 rstDatabase.ReplaceDatabase = true;
 rstDatabase.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
}
```

This how I call the function: `RestoreDatabase("myDb" , "D:\\myFile.bak" , "10.0.0.1" , "myUserName" , "Admin123");`

**Exception:**

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Restore failed for Server '10.0.0.1'.  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Directory lookup for the file "D:\Database\v2014\Default\Rdb\UDB\GSWarehouse\GSWarehouse.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.).
>       File 'GSWarehouse' cannot be restored to 'D:\Database\v2014\Default\Rdb\UDB\GSWarehouse\GSWarehouse.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>       Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>       RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server server, StringCollection queries)
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
>          at Lib.Mail.MailPage11.RestoreDatabase(String databaseName, String backUpFile, String serverName, String userName, String password)

Note:

If I create manually the folder `\GSWarehouse` inside the directory `D:\Database\v2014\Default\Rdb\UDB` the exeption gone.

my question: I need a general solution for creating this folder.

maybe something like:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(thePathFromTheExeption))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(thePathFromTheExeption)
```

Comment: Upvote for pasting your exceptions this time and a well formatted question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the missing directory:

```
if(!Directory.Exists("D:\Database\v2014\Default\Rdb\UDB\GSWarehouse"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(thePathFromTheExeption)
```